# How to reload dynamically configured Rewrite options in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

I am populating redirects from a database table in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app.

The `Configure` method obviously doesn't get re-run on every request, so I basically have to restart my site if any redirects change in the database.

Any hints on how to trigger the rewrite middleware specifically, or restart the whole site (hosted in Azure) based on changes in the database (even a webhook style message from my admin site to the production site)?

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyRedirects(this IApplicationBuilder app, MyDbContext context)
{
     var options = new RewriteOptions();
     var redirects = context.Redirects.ToList();

     foreach (var redirect in redirects)
     {
          options.AddRedirect(redirect.MatchUrl, redirect.RedirectToUrl, redirect.StatusCode);
     }

     app.UseRewriter(options);
     return app;
}
```